# PHP json encode and Node.js decode utf8mb4_unicode_ci strings

Tags: php, node.js, json, utf-8, utf8mb4

On my server, the database is encode in `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
I'm writing an API to serve data in JSON.
The PHP function `json_encode` only accepts `utf8`.

I'm not able to build the full chain:

`strings encoded in utf8mb4_unicode_ci` => `utf8` => `json` => `API` => `JavaScript` => `strings encoded in utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

For example,  `$str = "Linéaire "`;

From `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8` I already try the PHP functions `utf8_encode(str)` and
`mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252')` that return respectively:

- `"Lin\u00c3\u00a9aire \u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0080"`
- `"Lin\u00c3\u00a9aire \u00f0\u0178\u02dc\u20ac"`

Both functions do not return the same result. I don't know which one to choose.
Furthermore, I don't know how to unescape the string on client side  in JavaScript.

Comment: The `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is an internal Mysql UTF8 encoding variant. It has nothing to do with the client interaction. Since you land that `SET NAMES 'utf8'` query, you are getting the UTF8 data from the DB. No additional manipulations required. Just `print json_encode($sth->fetchAll());` and you'r fine. This is what UTF8 was created for after all - forget about encoding conversions. And you don't need to unescape something at client side, just `let data = JSON.parse(raw_json);`.

Comment: @Jared If I do not convert data in `utf8`, I can't use `json_encode()`. The function returns the `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` error.

Comment: After connecting to DBMS run the `SET NAMES 'utf8'` query and DBMS will return the UTF8 data for the subsequent queries.